# Redirect a file stream of a child process

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to control a child process' streams. Basically, I wanted to execute a program programmatically, create pipe lines for console output, console input, and error stream, but also pipe lines for file streams. 
For example,

```
int main (int, char * []) {
    printf ("Hello, World!\n"); // I want to capture this,
    FILE * fp = fopen ("test.txt", "r"); // send data through this stream,
    fclose (fp);
    fprintf (stderr, "Bye, World!\b"); // and finally capture this message.
    return 0;
}
```

My goal is to execute a program such as Microsoft Words and send read file data to the program. I am creating a encryption software that keeps data in a drive and pull out data securely when needed. SanDisk vault thing did similar job, but it seems like it created a temporary file somewhere in the hard disk, but I do not want to create temporary files.

I consulted Google, and Google showed `popen` function and `CreatePipe` function, but these functions created pipe lines for stdout, stdin, and stderr streams but no file streams.

I want both Linux and Windows, but Windows OS is on my first list.

Comment: Could you pick one of {linux, winapi} instead of both?

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish? This question sounds like your idea of a solution, without actually specifying the real problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to have a control over file operations made by certain process. A general solution to this (in WIndows) is a file system minifilter driver. SUch a driver sees all file operations made by processes (including the kernel) and can change them on the fly. For example, when it detects that process X is attempting to write data to file Y, it can encrypt the data.

However, developing a file system minifilter driver is not an easy task. I expect it being more difficult than developing a drive encryption software, such as Bitlocker or TrueCrypt, since file systems are really complicated beasts.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it is easy for a parent process to control `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` is because they are the only streams that the child process does not actually open. That is, from the child's point of view, they were already up and running when it started. Therefore, the parent only needs to provide alternative versions of `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` before starting the child. To do so you can use pipes, but you could use standard files too.

> I want to control a child process' streams. Basically, I wanted to execute a program programmatically, create pipe lines for console output, console input, and error stream, but also pipe lines for file streams.

This is unclear. To replace the console output, input and error streams you can use the pipe functions you described. As for files 'streams', they will be opened by the child process itself and you will have little control over those unless you can influence which file the child actually open.

You can, for example, create a [named pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe) named `test.txt` (using `mkfifo`) and you child process will mistakenly use this pipe as if it were a file. It behaves really differently and this can cause problems (`seek` is forbiden, writing then reading back does not have the expected behaviour, etc...), but might work with simple programs.

You might want use a proper file instead. If your goal is to not perform disk accesses, you can use a [memory-mapped file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file) which can easily be created in `/dev/shm` on most Linux systems.

Comment: May really the child process treat the named pipe you created as a file? Named pipes AFAIK are placed into a different name space than regular files do (they actually are files in their own file system).

Comment: I don't know for Windows. On Linux I regularly use named pipes to trick programs that do not use stdin, but reads from a file, to read from stdin. Example: `cp <(echo "foo") file.txt` will create `file.txt` containing `foo`.